# Changing limits of integration in $\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(u - \mu)^2) \, dv$

Tags: integration

Changing limits of integration in

$$\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(u - \mu)^2) \, du = \int^{\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp (-\frac{1}{2}v^2) \, dv$$

I understand I use integration by substitution, but what I don't understand is how the (upper) limit of integration change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

$$  \frac{u-\mu}{\sigma}=v$$

Comment: This is for the substitution? That I understand, but how did the upper limit of integration change? $x \rightarrow \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$

Comment: when you make a substitution the limits of integration need to be changed accordingly. So, if you put $u=x$ in this substitution you will get this upper limit.